# Why does JSLint say "anonymous function does not always return a value" for an event handler?

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function, jslint, eventhandler

When I [JSLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) this code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){ 
    if ($("#chaptersFunctionality").length !== 0) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13')
            return false;
        if ($("#kelvin").val() === "" && $("#caleb").attr("title") === "Show all steps") {
            switch(e.which){
            case 39:    if ((parseInt(currentAnchor)+1) < parseInt(maxi))
                expandMe(++currentAnchor);
                break;
            case 37:    if (currentAnchor > 0)
                expandMe(currentAnchor-1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

...I get plenty of warnings, most of which I grok, but this one has me stumped:
"*anonymous function does not always return a value*"

Why does it say this? An event handler is not an anonymous function, is it?
And it's not returning any value anyway, is it?
So what does this mean, and what would [moll,pac]ify the linter?

Comment: An event handler is a function. That function can be anonymous (and is in your code sample). An event handler may also return a value (and does so in your code sample, see the `return false` line). However, if the first inner `if` branch is not taken, then no `return` statement is executed, and your handler will default to returning `undefined`. It looks like JSLint doesn't appreciate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSLint warns you any time a function has some branches that encounter a `return` and other branches that terminate without encountering a `return`. JSLint thinks that a function should either *always* explicitly return a value or *never* explicitly return a value. A function that *sometimes* explicitly returns a value earns itself a warning. Your code does `return false` in one case and otherwise never uses `return`.

If you want to pacify JSLint, you may place a `return undefined;` at the bottom of your function so that it always explicitly returns something.

Now, for my opinion:

When it comes to event listeners, it is 100% acceptable to return value only sometimes. The browser's internal engine that uses your event listener `return` value is already programmed to accept a return value or the lack of a return value.

Because the practice of not returning a value in an event listener is perfectly normal, this does not harm the readability of your code. I think you can safely ignore JSLint in this case.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The function doesn't "sometimes return a value" and it can't "lack a return value". The function *is* returning `undefined` in those cases whether you do it yourself or not. I'd suggest not ignoring the error and pacifying JSLint the way you initially suggest. As [Crockford says, JSLint will hurt your feelings](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), but that's the point. If you want consistent code, particularly when working in a distributed group, linters will dispense with feelings and keep all of your code within the linter's bounds. That's their *raison d'etre*. ;^)

Comment: @ruffin I've changed "return" to "explicitly return" in those cases. I think the rest of your comment is very good; it's helped me understand a little better the purpose of linters.

Comment: Nice -- it's minor, but important, especially when JSLinting, I think. Compare to Crockford's rule on "insecure ^" in regular expressions. His bias is always for explicitly taking control and responsibility. So here, if you explicitly return `undefined` in the null case, even if some random JavaScript engine's default *isn't* to return `undefined` when a function doesn't use `return`, your function would continue operating the same as it used to. Anyhow, cool, thanks. Sorry to nitpick.